# Is there a way to make Dictation the default type-in method instead of the Keyboard (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, microphone, voice-dictation

Each time we want to use the dictation option (on an iPhone at least), we need to click on the microphone button on the keyboard

[image]

Is there a way to automatically use dictation when we want to type-in something ? In other words, make it the default type-in option. Needing to click on the microphone each time is really annoying, that's why I'm asking.

Thanks for your support !

Comment: Seems like something a 3rd party “keyboard” app might be able to do.

Comment: @TomGewecke Yeah, I also thought about it but unfortunately Apple doesn't allow 3rd party keyboard to access the microphone https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html       "Custom keyboards, like all app extensions in iOS 8.0, have no access to the device microphone, so dictation input is not possible." I never understood why they forbid that.

Comment: How about having Voice Control turned on by default?  It's dictation is too slow on my older device, but maybe on a newer one....

Comment: @TomGewecke I've just googled about voice control, and even tough it could work, it's not much different from the current situation. In the sense that instead of clicking the microphone each time, one would need to say "Dictation mode" each time. But it doesn't allow to set Dictation as the default type-in method.